# HVAC duct issues

Tags: hvac, ducts

Purchased a home a few months ago that was gut rehabbed with new AC + furnace + ductwork and left vacant for a year. A few weeks after moving in I took a chandelier out of the ceiling in the dining room. When I reached into the ceiling hole I heard the AC kick on and cold air was blowing hard in that ceiling space. Above that room is our master bedroom - the closest floor vent seemed to have cold air output that was normal. However that vent made faint popping noises at a regular interval after the AC would shut off, worse at night. Was a bit annoying to sleep with but we got used to it.

Now it's furnace season and the master bedroom is popping and creaking like crazy. Mostly again at night when the temperature drops but it's 10x as loud as the AC was and the popping sounds come from several sides of the room, almost like they're coming from the walls of the closet across from the vent.

I called some companies that do camera inspections of ducts but most said they do mostly commercial work and I should call an HVAC company (or tried to sell a cleaning instead). Out of 8 HVAC companies all have said they don't do inspections and would simply open up the ceiling looking for something to repair (or don't investigate duct issues at all).

Anyone experienced this before or have tips on who we should engage to help? Are camera inspections residential ducts this rare because it's unlikely to help diagnose leaks?

Comment: You might have to revise to ask something more specific. We're not a discussion forum. Are you asking who to hire? Inspection rarity is a localized issue, but you can buy a bore camera for $40 and do it yourself.

Comment: For what it's worth, the main trunk in my house ticks quite a bit. It bothered me when we moved in. After a couple years you won't notice it anymore.

Comment: I would presume that what you're hearing is the duct material creaking as it expands and contracts due to the hot/cold air moving through it. You probably won't be able to see this happen and there's probably not a lot you can do to fix it without opening the walls. If they used flexible duct, it should happen less, but there's still a metal boot behind the register that will move as the temp changes.

Comment: Mine pop real bad if I use pleated filters as soon as they get the least bit dirty. Use fiberglass filters. Heat will always make it crinkle as it cools, but too high of a static pressure inside and they will pop just like in *Die Hard* when it starts and stops. On one return duct I have a board propped against the wall to permanently indent the cross hatch so it can't pop.